# How to resolve C printf %b format warnings

Tags: c, gnu, gcc-warning

I am getting warning for below program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 0xff;
    printf("%B\n", num);
    printf("%b\n", ~num);
    printf("%b\n", ~num+1);
    return 0;
}
```

warning

```
gcc binary-format-print.c
binary-format-print.c: In function ‘main’:
binary-format-print.c:6:18: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘B’ in format [-Wformat=]
    6 |         printf("%B\n", num);
      |                  ^
binary-format-print.c:6:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    6 |         printf("%B\n", num);
      |                ^~~~~~
binary-format-print.c:7:18: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘b’ in format [-Wformat=]
    7 |         printf("%b\n", ~num);
      |                  ^
binary-format-print.c:7:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    7 |         printf("%b\n", ~num);
      |                ^~~~~~
binary-format-print.c:8:18: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘b’ in format [-Wformat=]
    8 |         printf("%b\n", ~num+1);
      |                  ^
binary-format-print.c:8:16: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
    8 |         printf("%b\n", ~num+1);
```

ldd version,

```
❯ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

gcc version

```
❯ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I suppose gnu C supports binary print format.
Then why such warnings?

How to resolve these warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Comment: I have checked this answer before asking this question, this answer is of interest https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993946/2270386 but if the support is added then why warnings?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Your info is outdated. It is currently standard "b,B,o,u,x,X The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned binary (b or B), unsigned octal
(o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; [...]"

Comment: @mrigendra understood. I retracted my close-duplicate vote.

Comment: @ikegami: The C 2023 draft is not the standard yet. ISO shows it as [under development](https://www.iso.org/standard/82075.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need gcc 12+

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:6:14: warning: ISO C does not support the '%B' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
    6 |     printf("%B\n", num);
      |              ^
<source>:7:14: warning: ISO C17 does not support the '%b' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
    7 |     printf("%b\n", ~num);
      |              ^
<source>:8:14: warning: ISO C17 does not support the '%b' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
    8 |     printf("%b\n", ~num+1);
      |              ^
```

```
11111111
11111111111111111111111100000000
11111111111111111111111100000001
```

With `-std=c2x`,

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:6:14: warning: ISO C does not support the '%B' gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]
    6 |     printf("%B\n", num);
      |              ^
```

```
11111111
11111111111111111111111100000000
11111111111111111111111100000001
```

Comment: with gcc-12 I see no warnings.